# How many ways can (0,1,-1) sum to numbers (15 through to 30)

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, binomial-distribution

I am currently trying to solve a statistics problem involving random guessing in multiple choice tests and the probability of passing said test. In order to work out the probability of passing i need to calculate the number of ways that the numbers -1, 0 and 1 can sum together, only 30 times, and equal the numbers 15 through to 30.

I was wondering if anyone knew of any formulas or programs that could give me the result of this problem.

Comment: Are the ways ordered?  So is $-1,0,1$ different from $-1,1,0$?

Comment: There are 30 questions in the multiple choice test, and on each question there is a third chance of receiving -1, 0, 1 from guessing. So there will be an order of 30 based on the results of each question, so in the context of the questions i guess there is a difference as there can be many orders that sum to the same number.

Comment: In fact there are six orders for $-1,0$ and $1$, plus for a total of zero there is the chance of $0,0,0$.  You need to know what question you are asking.  For three questions and total score of zero, is it $7$?. If not, what is it?  That is few enough to count by hand.

Comment: The test is out of 30 questions, where a pass is greater or equal to 50% of total marks. Therefore between 15 and 30. In each question you can either receive a mark of -1, 0, 1 depending on which answer is guessed. For example one possible order would be : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0,] 
I want to know how many of these orders sum to the numbers 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30. 
I'm sorry this is the only way i can really explain it, I hope it clarifies some things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, to score $15$ you can have $15 \ 1$'s and the rest $0$'s, $16\ 1$'s, $13\ 0$'s and one $-1$, or ... $22\ 1$'s, one $0$, and $7\ -1$'s.  You are looking for the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).  To take the case of $19\ 1$'s, $7\ 0$'s and $4\ -1$'s there are ${30 \choose 19}{11 \choose 4}={30 \choose 19,7,4}=\frac {30!}{19!7!4!}=18027009000$ possibilities because you can first choose the $19$ questions to get $1$ out of the $30$, then choose $4$ of the remaining $11$ to be $-1$.  Now you need to sum over the numbers of $1$ and $0$ answers.  If we let $i$ be the number of $1$ answers and $j$ be the number of $-1$ answers we need $30 \ge i \ge 15, 30-i \ge j, i-15 \ge j$ and the result is $$\sum_{1=15}^{30}\sum_{j=0}^{\min(30-i,i-15)}{30 \choose i,j,30-i-j}=\sum_{1=15}^{30}\sum_{j=0}^{\min(30-i,i-15)}\frac{30!}{i!j!(30-i-j)!}$$  You can automate this in a spreadsheet using fixed and relative addressing, then copy right and down.